# Can I use Mapbox as an open source maps provider in Qgis?

Tags: uses-of-open-data

I am working in Qgis and using their satellite map.
In the [Mapbox website](https://www.mapbox.com/about/open/)  the said that they are an "open source".
Just for being sure: can I use their maps like OSM maps? 
Give them credit and use them in Fiverr?
Tanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is [open source](https://github.com/mapbox/), but if you want to use their service, that comes with constraints. The easiest summary is the [Pricing page](https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/).

Note that the underlying data is [still OSM](https://www.mapbox.com/help/osm-and-mapbox/). There are lots of ways to consume that data, including a range of rendering and data query options.

Answer (score 0):

I sent to the customer support this message [image] 
The sent me this answer  [image] and a list of links. 
I think that this answer is pretty clear. 
The way to give Mapbox their credit is to go Properties in the Layers Panel [image]
and then to click on the "Place the credit..." bar [image]
The credit will shows on the right cornet of the map [image]

As the Mapbox answer is as good as it can get I think it will be a good reinforcement if some one alas will ask the same question and post one more "Yes" in this forum.
Thanks

The link list from Mapbox:

[Getting Started guides](https://www.mapbox.com/help/#get-started-with-mapbox)

[How Mapbox Works](https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/) 
[Getting Started with Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/help/getting-started-mapbox-studio-1/)

[Adding Custom Data](https://www.mapbox.com/help/add-custom-data/)

[Uploads Help](https://www.mapbox.com/help/uploads/)

[Dataset Editor](https://www.mapbox.com/help/getting-started-studio-datasets/)

Comment: Telling the rest of us that you want to use QGIS would have been worth putting in the question.

Comment: You are right and I change the headline and the question